# Limit on connector cable for HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor

Tags: communication, hc-sr04

Is there a limit for the connector distance between an arduino and a HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor?

I have a set-up for measuring a liquid's level in a tank. The benchtop version worked OK, but when I deployed it, I introduced a 10meter cat5 cable connecting the HC-SR04 to the arduino, it is giving me strange distance readings (they are showing the same distance, even though the level has changed significantly).

The 10m of cat5 is the only element that has changed from the benchtop tests.

Is this length of cat5 a potential problem? If so how can I diagnose it? I have a multimeter and basic oscilloscope?

Update:
I measured 4.77v across the sensor's 5v/GND on the breadboard with arduino and 4.65v on the sensor itself.

Comment: Check the voltage levels at the sensor and at the input of the Arduino (for the echo and trigger you might need the oscilloscope to get a good reading). Over that length you might have significant voltage drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cat 5.e cable is specially designed to carry on differential (or balanced) signals (that is why it consists of four twisted pairs - each pair is like tunnel for signal)

On the other hand, the ultrasonic sensor utilizes non-balanced, non-differential signal of high frequency, so, the valid length of cable, that couldn't destroy the data in the signal accuracy is about 0.3-0.5 meter only.

You can check my words by comparing a plots of the signal (on controller input pin) with 10cm and 10m cables.

The digital signal must have nice, square form like this:

[image]

But the signal, which is passed through long line of wire can be look like this:
[image]

And this is bad, because now the controller could not interpret this signal shape correctly.

Comment: Is there a way of 'squaring' off the signal at the end of the long cable?

Comment: Yes and no, actually. The simplest way to do this - is to place the controller as near as possible to the sensor. The other way implies the idea of using differential signals - for example, use four of RS485 (i.e, the MAX485 integrated circuit) transceivers. Use one pair of them to send the Trig signal from the MCU, and another pair - to send the Echo signal